# No notification sound on the emulator

Tags: android, notifications

I am going nuts with a problem with `notifications` on Android: While I was developing my project, suddenly the emulator plays no notification sounds anymore for `API` 26 and higher,

e.g. the API which require a channel.
Of course I have set up a channel and it has worked great before! I have reinstalled the app, deleted the channel, even set up another AVD with a `API` 27, same result: no sound ! (the notification does pop up)

Obviously I have checked that notification sounds are enabled, also for this specific channel, all seems OK, just no sounds.
If I play a test using:

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)).play();
```

it works as it should, so no hardware problem.
On lower `APIs` pre 26 where you don't need a channel, the sound does play.

Anybody had the same problem?

```
//make the channel
//The Config class is imported and the constants resolved, not the problem


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    Config.CHANNEL_1_ID,
                    Config.CHANNEL_1_NAME,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            channel.setDescription(Config.CHANNEL_1_DESC);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);

          NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

// send notification
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Config.CHANNEL_1_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setAutoCancel(false)
                        .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        mNotificationMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Post the code...

Comment: As I said, it has suddenly stopped working without touching the notification code. Was working before.

Also when I send a notification via Firebase while the app is in the background, the system handles the notification instead of the app. Same behaviour: no sound.

Also downloaded some generic sample project for notification channels: no sound.
I think there is something wrong with the emulator.

Answer (score 18):

Seems I found the answer: I had to go through the "Finish setting up your Android SDK" wizard on the emulator. Clicked "skip" for everything, now it seems to work again.
Weirdly enough, I didn't do that initially and still the notifications worked as expected... duh !

Comment: This was indeed the case with a Pixel API 28 (Android 9 with Google Play) AVD on Android Studio 3.3.2.

Comment: Oh gosh. Spending few hours of debugging for such nonsense issue..

Comment: Sure would be nice if the tutorials EVERYWHERE included this crucial step. I have been dealing with this all day. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

On Pie 9.0 (api 28), you need to **complete setup process**. After doing it, the **sound of notification channels will run well**. It is same for both Emulator and physical devices.
If you have not done it, all notification on device will be run on silent, regardless of importance level.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for the answer. Please elaborate on "setup process". What do you mean by it? What does that process involves? The steps.

Comment: You will see this notification, It shows the wizard to complete the setup: 
1. https://i.ibb.co/ctXHw6P/Screenshot-1563463541.png
2. https://i.ibb.co/gVKxnNy/Screenshot-1563463524.png

Answer (score 3):

You may need to check Tools->SDK Manager->Appearance & Bahaviour->Notifications "Play sound" checkbox for the "Android emulator" and "Android" to get notifications sounds (i.e. when other sounds work, but there's not notification sound).

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the ring volume on the emulator. Apparently it was on zero by default and there was no indication for it on the top bar. Also when pressing the volume keys it would open the media volume and not the ring volume! I had to increase the ring volume via android settings -> sound.