# NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH still no sound

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create notifications in android but no matter what importance and priority I set, there's no sound. I am assuming sound (ringtone) is handle by android itself I don't need to provide any mp3/wav file. I am trying on android 8.1 (actual device), 8.0 (emulator) and 8.1 (emulator). Notification channel created on actual device has sound off by default, I don't know why and on emulator sound is on but still no sound played on notification

Here is my code:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    createNotificationChannel();
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("New Notification")
            .setContentText("Lorem Ipsum")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "basic-channel";
        String description = "Lorem Ipsum";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

**Channel on Actual Device**

[image: actual device]

**Channel on Emulator**

[image: emulator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root Cause:
For actual device, that's OEM's problem, which in my case is Xiaomi and I found this link threema.ch/en/faq/notification_channels_xiaomi which says that xiaomi sets sound=off for all app except select few like FB, whatsApp, etc.

For emulator, we need to complete the setup process after which notification starts making sound.

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful for Huawei as well; heads-up notifications will only show if I go to my app's settings > Notifications > Notification Type > Banners and switch on banners

Answer (score 1):

When you build the notification, you need to indicate that you want to use the default system values:

```
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
```

And remember to clear the app data or reinstall the app to properly recreate the notification channel. A notification channel will retain its initial configuration even if you recreate it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

```
//Define sound URI
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("New Notification")
            .setContentText("Lorem Ipsum")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            .setSound(soundUri); //This sets the sound to play
```

Comment: still no sound on either actual device or emulator

Comment: don't want to play custom sound. My actual device is Xiaomi and I found this link https://threema.ch/en/faq/notification_channels_xiaomi which says that xiaomi sets sound=off for all app except select few like FB, whatsApp, etc. Now I am thinking about emulators, do they play notification sound ever?

Comment: it's plays sound . Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986070/no-notification-sound-on-the-emulator