# NotificationChannel sound needs restart phone

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, notifications

I am trying to provide local notification into my App with my custom sound.

I created simple app in Visual Studio, and I want show notification on FAB Click.
My problem is that, notification is displaying, but without sound.

But... After phone restart - notification works properly with sound!

My code - create channel method called in `OnCreate()`:

```
    string channelId = "1";
    string channelName = "a";
    int notificationId = 0;

    private void createNotificationChannel()
    {
        var notMgr = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        var uri = new Android.Net.Uri.Builder()
                .Scheme(ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource)
                .Authority(Resources.GetResourcePackageName(Resource.Raw.neworder4))
                .AppendPath(Resources.GetResourceTypeName(Resource.Raw.neworder4))
                .AppendPath(Resources.GetResourceEntryName(Resource.Raw.neworder4))
                .Build();
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {

            if (notMgr.GetNotificationChannel(channelId) == null)
            {
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationImportance.Default);
                channel.Description = channelName;

                var aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
                        .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();
                channel.SetSound(uri, aa);

                notMgr.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Show notification on FAB click:

```
private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var notMgr = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationId = notificationId + 1;


        var not = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .SetContentText("test")
            .SetContentTitle("test")

            .Build();

        notMgr.Notify(notificationId, not);
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I don't want to require my users to reboot phones after app install.

Resource.Raw.neworder4 is mp3 file, and is set as Android Resource.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to play custom sound for Local Notification, it works fine, you can take a look:

Creating channel:

```
 string channelId = "location_notification";
    string channelName = "localnotification";
    int notificationId = 1000;
void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }

        Android.Net.Uri sound = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + Application.Context.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.MyAudio);
        var aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
                .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();
        var channelDescription = "local notification!!!!";
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationImportance.Max)
        {
            Description = channelDescription
        };
        channel.SetSound(sound,aa);
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

Building the notification:

```
 private void Button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        // Build the notification:
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                      .SetAutoCancel(true) // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
                      .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
                      .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked") // Set the title
                                                         //.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm))
                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.addreminder); // This is the icon to display

        // Finally, publish the notification:
        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder.Build());          
    }
```

Comment: Nothing changed, still phone reboot is necessary, I tried with MP3, OGG, and Wav files.
Steps to reproduce: 1. Factory reset emulator. 2. Install application, 3. click button. Notification is showed but have no sound. Emulator with android 10

Comment: @PiotrK Yes, I also test this sample at emulator 10 and 8.1, it works fine, has no problem. So can you try to test at emulator 8.1? Emulator 9.0 have some problem, but you need to finish Android Steup, it will alao works.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for one part of my problem (for Emulator):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56935747

I tested notifications on physical phone with android 9.0, and there is no sound for notifications without restart phone.

For now I think provided solution is close enough for me.